# How to find the IP address of an RDS instance using the AWS SDK when dig won't suffice?

Tags: dns, aws-sdk, amazon-rds

**Please note:** flavors of this question have been asked in the past, but they all assumed that there would be a DNS A record that could be passed into a `dig` lookup. That's not the case here.

---

When you create a new RDS using the AWS SDK, is there *anything* you can do to get that instance's IP address? I know I could do a DNS `dig` but that requires having a DNS name to feed the `dig` in the first place. I see `DBInstance` has an ARN and an instance identifier associated with it, but those are not the same as a DNS endpoint/IPv4, etc.

Comment: You really shouldn't use the IP address since it is subject to change. Why not just use the endpoint address?

Comment: @MarkB you mean `DBInstance.getEndpoint().getAddress()`?

Comment: Yes, use the endpoint address provided by the RDS service instead of trying to resolve the IP.

Answer (score 1):

Use nslookup to the DB instance endpoint

nslookup myexampledb.xxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com

Server: xx.xx.xx.xx
Address: xx.xx.xx.xx#53

Comment: Thanks @MuthuKumar K (+1) but I'm using the SDK not the web UI, how would I get `myexampledb.xxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com` value from the [`DBInstance`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/rds/model/DBInstance.html)?

Comment: This post does not answer the question asked.